# Accurev command for promoting all files upstream

Tags: accurev

I am wondering if there is a command that can be executed to move files from one stream to the parent stream? Accurev appears to say you can use the -s and -S to specify the stream, but it does not appear to work for my needs. I have a stream like:

Base --> Integration --> Release --> Developer Workspace.

I can create commands to promote my changes from the developer workspace to release. Now I want to create a command that will promote files on the server upstream. So for example if there are files in Release I would like to promote them all to Integration. Any thought?

Here is what I used to promote from my workspace to the release stream on the server, but not that its there I don't have a workspace location I can specify

```
SET WORKSPACES="C:\ITTraining\AccuRev\New Hire Code\"*
c:
cd %WORKSPACE%

REM prompts user to log into accurev prior to performing actions
if errorlevel 1 goto exit

FOR /D %%G IN (%WORKSPACES%) DO (

    ECHO Starting update to: %%G

    ECHO Starting update to: %%G
    REM Used to run an update on the workspace
    ECHO accurev update

    ECHO adding external content to: %%G
    ECHO accurev add -x -c "new content"

    ECHO promoting content to: %%G
    REM used to promote all content in the workspace that is modified or kept
    ECHO accurev promote -K -p -c "Standard curriculum updates"
    accurev promote * -s ltg_PDEBath05_JAR_REL_INT
    cd %%G

)
```

Answer (score 2):

accurev promote -s Release -S Integration -d